# InfluxDB v1.8: subquery using MAX selector

Tags: sql, postgresql, influxdb

I'm using InfluxDB 1.8 and trying to make a little more complex query than Influx was made for.

I want to retrieve all data that refers to the last month stored, based on tag and field values that my script stores (not the default "time" field that Influx creates). Say we have this `infos` measurement:

| time | field_month | field_week | tag_month | tag_week | some_data |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1631668119209113500 | 8 | 1 | 8 | 1 | random |
| 1631668119209113500 | 8 | 2 | 8 | 2 | random |
| 1631668119209113500 | 8 | 3 | 8 | 3 | random |
| 1631668119209113500 | 9 | 1 | 9 | 1 | random |
| 1631668119209113500 | 9 | 1 | 9 | 1 | random |
| 1631668119209113500 | 9 | 2 | 9 | 2 | random |

Which 8 refers to August, 9 to September, and then `some_data` that is stored on a given week of that month.

I can use [MAX selector](https://docs.influxdata.com/influxdb/v1.8/query_language/functions/#max) at `field_month` to get the last month of the year stored (can't use [Flux date package](https://docs.influxdata.com/influxdb/v2.0/reference/flux/stdlib/date/) because I'm using v1.8). Further, I want the data grouped by `tag_month` and `tag_week` so I can `COUNT` how many times `some_data` was stored on each week of the month, that's why the same data is repeated in field and tag keys. Something like that:

1. `SELECT COUNT(field_month) FROM infos WHERE field_month = 9 GROUP BY tag_month, tag_week`

Replacing 9 by MAX Selector:

2. `SELECT COUNT(field_month) FROM infos WHERE field_month = (SELECT MAX(field_month) FROM infos) GROUP BY tag_month, tag_week`

The first query works ([*see results here*](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CJhOI.png)), but not the second.

Am I doing something wrong? Is there any other possibility to make this work in v1.8?

**NOTE:** I know Influx wasn't supposed to be used like that. I've tried and managed this easily with PostgreSQL, using an adapted form of the second query above. But while we straighten things up to use Postgres, we have to use InfluxDB v1.8.

Answer (score 0):

in postgresql you can try :

```
SELECT COUNT(field_month) FROM infos WHERE field_month = 
(SELECT field_month FROM infos ORDER BY field_month DESC limit 1)
GROUP BY tag_month, tag_week;
```

Comment: i dont know how to use limit in InfluxDB but I think this can suggest the solution for you.

Comment: Good try, but it didn't work. Tried this query: 

`SELECT COUNT(field_month) FROM infos WHERE field_month = (SELECT field_month FROM infos ORDER BY field_month DESC LIMIT 1) GROUP BY tag_month, tag_week`

The result was the same from the 2nd query on my question, it didn't even prompt an error message. I'm starting to think that Influx does not allow subquerys on WHERE clause.